# Problem with precision qualifiers in a shader for android

Tags: love2d, glsles

I had a problem rendering with a shader for Android on Löve2d due to the precision of the floats, so I wanted to add these precompilation instructions so that the floats are automatically `highp` if possible.

```c
#ifdef GL_ES 
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif
#endif
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: highp : overloaded functions must have the same parameter precision qualifiers for argument 1
ERROR: highp : overloaded functions must have the same parameter precision qualifiers for argument 3
ERROR: highp : overloaded functions must have the same parameter precision qualifiers for argument 4
```

Which matches this line:

```c
vec4 effect(vec4 color, Image texture, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 screen_coords)
```

My question is why and how to fix it? Because on the examples I saw on the Löve2d forum it seemed to work.

The version of OpenGL ES on the device that produces this error is 3.2 if that helps.

Comment: It's saying `overloaded functions`. That implies that there's some other function also called `effect` perhaps with different explicit qualifiers. If there's no other function called `effect` that you're aware of then perhaps it's part of `Löve2d` internals. Maybe try renaming the function?

Comment: I also think it must be an internal Löve2d issue, it seemed to work on older versions and I only have this shader with one function called `effect`. I am also waiting for an answer on the official forum but I still haven't received one.

And I can't rename it, it's the function name used by Löve2d for fragment shaders, the parameters sent there are sent by the framework.